# Refiguring K-Means clustering criterias

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, k-means

Let's say I have some data, an array of array, or a DataFrame, like:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  1  2
1  0  1  0  3
2  0  0  0  4
```

After Making some k-means clustering on it, like this :

```
centroids, _ = cluster.vq.kmeans(rep.values, nb_clusters, iter=100)
idx, _ = cluster.vq.vq(rep.values, centroids)
```

I got 2 clusters making sense to me. However, I would like to know a way to understand How/Why K-means arrived to this cluster, eg. **Which of features a, b, c, d where the most relevant to separate clusters, etc.**

Does anyone knows a way to do this ? or to look a way to do it ? In python, or more theoretically ?

Thanks in advance for considering my question.

Answer (score 1):

K-means does not treat any variable special.

On contrary, it is very sensitive to scale. Rescale your data (each dimension with a different scale), and your results may change drastically.

If you want a **decision-tree like explanation, train a decision tree on the clusters** - k-means cannot provide this, but nothing prevents you from analyzing the clustering result... in fact, you should always carefully analyze a clustering result, as it will frequently be just as good as a random partitioning for practical purposes. So also, always include such "random voronoi cell partitions" in your experimental setup, to make sure that you actually have *some* improvement.

Answer (score 0):

AS the other guys pointed out, one of the disadvantages of (the original) K-Means is that it treats all feature the same, regardless of their degree of relevance to the actual problem.

If you are interested in a version of K-Means that allows different features to have different weights you could take a look in this paper: [Minkowski metric, feature weighting and anomalous cluster initializing in K-Means clustering](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232282003_Author%27s_personal_copy_Minkowski_metric_feature_weighting_and_anomalous_cluster_initializing_in_K-Means_clustering/file/d912f508115a040b45.pdf)